# iOS 7: Footer of Table view section appear on left instead of Center

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I notice that `footer` of `UITableView` section (in static `UITableView`) appear on left instead of Centre as it used to be before.
I have no problem if this the normal behaviour in iOS 7.

Thus, my question is, is this the normal behaviour? if not, could I change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is normal behavior. In iOS 7, footer text is left aligned for both `plain` and `grouped` `UITableView` styles.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this the normal from `iOS 7.0` onwards.

**Ideally you should not try to change the normal behavior!!**

Since it is already answered that it is a normal behavior, try aligning your `UI design` to the same.